# IE7 issue with DIV, child div width taken from parent

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, width

IE7 issue with DIV, child div width taken from parent! It works fine in IE9 but IE7 shows child divs stacked vertically and 100% width of parent div. IE9 shows child divs stacking horizontally first, then to a second row as needed, and they are 100% of the childs width, depending on content.

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        background-image: url(/CIRCUITS/framework/Images/masterpagedefault/bg_texturedphoto.jpg);
        background-repeat: repeat;
    }
    .menuItems 
    {
        list-style-image: none;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding:5px 10px 10px 10px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    .menuItemHeader {
        background-color: #272727;
        padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
        margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        border-top: 1px;
        border-left: 1px;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        border-right: 1px;            
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #666;
    }
    .menuItemHeader2 {
        background-color: #272727;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        border-top: 1px;
        border-left: 1px;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        border-right: 1px;            
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #333;
    }
    .menuItemContainer2 {
        background-image: url(/CIRCUITS/framework/Images/masterpagedefault/dropshadow.png);
        background-repeat: repeat;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        border: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #333; 
        vertical-align:top;
    }
    .menuItemContainer {
        background-color: #333;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: white;
        text-align: left;
        border: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #666;
    }
    .menuFramework2 {
         background-image: url(/CIRCUITS/framework/Images/masterpagedefault/HSubmenuBG.png);
         border-top: none;
         border-left: solid;
         border-left-color: black;
         border-left-width: 1px;
         border-bottom: solid;
         border-bottom-color: black;
         border-bottom-width: 1px;
         border-right: solid;
         border-right-color: black;
         border-right-width: 1px;
         visibility: hidden;
         position: absolute;
         top: 10px;
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         font-size: 10px;
         color: white;
    }
    .menuFramework {
         background-image: url(/CIRCUITS/framework/Images/masterpagedefault/HSubmenuBG.png);
         border-top: none;
         border-left: solid;
         border-left-color: black;
         border-left-width: 1px;
         border-bottom: solid;
         border-bottom-color: black;
         border-bottom-width: 1px;
         border-right: solid;
         border-right-color: black;
         border-right-width: 1px;
         visibility: hidden;
         position: absolute;
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         font-size: 10px;
         color: white;
    }
    .MainMenu {
         background-image: url('/CIRCUITS/framework/Images/masterpagedefault/dropshadow.png');
         border-top-width: 0px; 
         border-left: 2px solid transparent;
         border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
         border-right: 2px solid transparent;
         visibility: hidden; 
         position: absolute;
         width: 1009px;
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         font-size: 10px;
         color: white;
         padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
         margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
         top: 55px;
    }
    .menulinks {
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         font-size: 11px;
         color: white;
         outline: none;
         text-decoration: none;
    }
    a {
         font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
         font-size:12px;
         color: white;
         outline:none;
     }
     a:link {
         text-decoration: none;
         outline:none;
     }
     a:visited {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: white;
         outline:none;
     }
     a:hover {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #99ccff;
         outline:none;
     }
     a:active {
         text-decoration: none;
         outline:none;
     }
</style>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
        var d = document; if (d.images) {
            if (!d.MM_p) d.MM_p = new Array();
            var i, j = d.MM_p.length, a = MM_preloadImages.arguments; for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                if (a[i].indexOf("#") != 0) { d.MM_p[j] = new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src = a[i]; }
        }
    }
    function On(objMenuButton, objMenu, TopOffset, LeftOffset, imgButton) {
        if (objMenu.style.visibility == "visible") {
            return;
        }
        //alert(document.getElementById("divER").style.clientLeft);
        //alert(document.getElementById("divER").clientLeft);
        //return;
        //alert(objMenuButton.offsetTop);
        objMenu.style.visibility = "visible";
        //objMenu.style.left = (objMenuButton.offsetLeft + LeftOffset) + "px";
        //alert(objMenu.offsetLeft);
        //alert(objMenu.style.bottom);
        //objMenu.style.top = (objMenuButton.offsetTop + objMenuButton.offsetHeight + TopOffset) + "px";
        //this.divER.style.left.
        //alert("bot:" + (parseInt(ImgHeight) + parseInt(TopOffset) + 0));
        //alert(objMenuButton.style.height);
        //alert(objMenu.style.left);
        //alert(objMenuButton.offsetLeft);
        imgButton.src = "/CIRCUITS/framework/Images/masterpagedefault/HMenuUA_On.png";
    }
    function Off(objMenu, imgButton) {
        //alert(event.srcElement.id + " " + objMenu.id);
        //alert(objMenu.id);
        imgButton.src = "/CIRCUITS/framework/Images/masterpagedefault/HMenuUA.png";
        objMenu.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
</script>
```

UA Menu Small Large Largest testryareyareyaetuyateru

Menu Item Small

Menu Item Two

Menu Item Three

Menu Item Four

Menu Item Five

Menu Item Six

UA Menu Small Large Largest ateru

Menu Item Small

Menu Item Two

Menu Item Three

Menu Item Four

Menu Item Five

Menu Item Six

UA Menu Small Large Largest aterudfhs dfhdfhdfh dahfh dfh afd a df hh

Menu Item Small

Menu Item Two

Menu Item Three

Menu Item Four

Menu Item Five

Menu Item Six

UA Menu Small Large Largest ateru

Menu Item Small

Menu Item Two

Menu Item Three

Menu Item Four

Menu Item Five

Menu Item Six

UA Menu Small Large Largest ateru

Menu Item Small

Menu Item Two

Menu Item Three

Menu Item Four

Menu Item Five

Menu Item Six

Comment: Just out of my curiosity; Where from came still any reason to spent time because of IE7 ?